# Why does selenium can't add event listener?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I tried this code (C#) :

```
string javascript = "window.document.addEventListener('domready', function(){alert('READY');}, false);console.log('test');"
((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript(javascript);
```

The formatted Javascript code is :

```
window.document.addEventListener(
  'domready', 
  function() {
    alert('READY');
  }, 
  false);
console.log('test');
```

The "READY" popup never show up. Do you have an idea on how to solve this problem ?

The javascript is executed as soon as the page start loading (the `console.log('test')` command is executed before anything is displayed on the screen).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the READY popup never shows because the event listener is added after 'domready' fires its event. You might be able to leverage document.readyState === "complete" to achieve what you want, by simply doing something like:

```
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
  // do stuff
} else {
  window.document.addEventListener('domready', doStuff);
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: But my log in the console shows as soon as the loading start. That's strange

Comment: Yup, unless I am missing something (which is possible), I would expect your console.log to show.  This is what is basically happening:


You first register a callback to execute when the page decides it is finished loading with 'domready'.  If the Javascript is injected AFTER the dom is ready, it will never fire because that event only happens once.


The console.log('test') is executed right away, regardless of whether or not the 'domready' event has fired. So, what I believe is happening is that the Javascript is being interpreted/executed AFTER 'domready' has already fired.